# How do I un-sort value counts by value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have values that represent a time difference. Rather than having `pd.Series.value_counts()` order the counts by the values, I'd rather have them ordered by the values themselves.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 3, 100).astype(int), columns=['Time Since'])

df['Time Since'].value_counts().plot.bar(figsize=(4, 4), title='Time Difference Plot')
plt.xlabel('Time Since Last Accident')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, it makes zero sense to plot time differences this way.

Comment: `df['Time Since'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(...)`

Comment: value_counts sets the parameter sort to True by default, you can set it to False. df['Time Since'].value_counts(sort = False).plot.bar(figsize=(4, 4), title='Time Difference Plot')

Comment: Excellent answers thank you. Both have worked.